# Access Implementation's property on variable of type Interface

Tags: kotlin, reflection, kotlin-reflect

I'm trying to access the delegate of the property (`id`) of a class (`FooImpl`). The problem is, this class implements an interface (`Foo`), and the property in question overrides a property of this interface. The delegate only exists in the class (not that it could exist in the interface).

The problem is that using the `::` operator on a variable of type `Foo` always returns the property of `Foo`, not that of the actual instance. The problem in code:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty0
import kotlin.reflect.jvm.isAccessible

interface Foo {
    val id: Int
}

class FooImpl(
    id: Int,
) : Foo {
    override val id: Int by lazy { id }
}

val <T> KProperty<T>.hasDelegate: Boolean
    get() = apply { isAccessible = true }.let { (it as KProperty0<T>).getDelegate() != null }

fun main() {
    val foo: Foo = FooImpl(1)
    println("foo::id.hasDelegate = ${foo::id.hasDelegate}")
    println("(foo as FooImpl)::id.hasDelegate = ${(foo as FooImpl)::id.hasDelegate}")
}
```

This prints:

```
foo::id.hasDelegate = false
(foo as FooImpl)::id.hasDelegate = true
```

But this requires compile-time knowledge of the correct implementation. What I'm looking for is accessing the correct propert without having to specify `FooImpl` there.

The information is present at runtime because the least (!) intrusive workaround I have found so far is adding `fun idProp(): KProperty0<*>` to `Foo` and `override fun idProp() = ::id` to `FooImpl` and accessing the property using that.

Is there any better way than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the owner of the property is resolved on compile time, not on runtime. When you do `foo::id` then `foo` (so `FooImpl`) become its bound receiver, but owner is still resolved to `Foo`. To fix this we wound need to "cast" property to another owner. Unfortunately, I didn't find a straightforward way to do this.

One solution I found is to use `foo::class` instead of `foo::id` as it resolves `KClass` on runtime, not on compile time. Then I came up with almost exactly the same code as @Tenfour04.

But if you don't mind using Kotlin internals that are public and not protected with any annotation, you can use much cleaner solution:

```kotlin
val KProperty0<*>.hasDelegate: Boolean
    get() = apply { isAccessible = true }.getDelegate() != null

fun KProperty0<*>.castToRuntimeType(): KProperty0<*> {
    require(this is PropertyReference0)
    return PropertyReference0Impl(boundReceiver, boundReceiver::class.java, name, signature, 0)
}

fun main() {
    val foo: Foo = FooImpl(1)
    println(foo::id.castToRuntimeType().hasDelegate) // true
}
```

We basically create a new instance of `KProperty`, copying all its data, but changing the owner to the same type as its bound receiver. As a result, we "cast" it to the runtime type. This is much simpler and it is also cleaner because we separated property casting and checking for a delegate.

Unfortunately, I think Kotlin reflection API is still missing a lot of features. There should be `hasDelegate()` function, so we don't have to provide receivers, which is not really needed to check if property is delegated. It should be possible to cast `KProperty` to another type. It should be possible to create bound properties with some API call. But first of all, it should be possible to do something like: `Foo::id(foo)`, so create `KProperty` of the runtime type of `foo`. And so on.

Comment: Thank you, that is probably the best I can hope for with the current state of things. Works for my purposes. Funnily enough, I was unable to adapt it to `KProperty1` (for receiverless Properties like `Foo::id`), since the class hierarchy there is different and completely `internal`.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this, but I don't know if there's a better way. The problem to work around is that `getDelegate()` has to return an actual instance of the delegate, so you need an instance of the class to be able to retrieve a delegate instance. It would really be nice if there was a `hasDelegate` property built in. Your version of `hasDelegate` will crash from the cast on unbound KProperty1's, which is all we have to work with when the specific class is unknown.

So to retrieve the delegate instance, we need to do search the class instance's member properties by name, which gives us a KProperty with covariant class type of the super-class type. Since it's covariant, we can call a consuming function like `getDelegate()` without casting to the invariant type. I think this logically should be safe, since we are passing an instance that we know has the matching type for the `::class` that we retrieved the property with.

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T: Any> KProperty1<T, *>.isDelegated(instance: T): Boolean =
    (instance::class.memberProperties.first { it.name == name } as KProperty1<T, *>).run {
        isAccessible = true
        getDelegate(instance) != null
    }

fun main() {
    val foo: Foo = Foo2()
    println("foo::id.hasDelegate = ${Foo::id.isDelegated(foo)}")
}
```